# Is it possible to quantify how much RAM is being used for graphics in Apple Silicon?

Tags: memory, apple-silicon

Much has been made of the Unified Memory in Apple Silicon SoCs: with some saying that it brings efficiencies; and others saying that more RAM will be used overall.

My old Intel integrated GPUs uses 1536 Mb of RAM for graphics (according to "About This Mac"), though it doesn't seem easy to identify this in Activity Monitor either.

Is it possible to get some kind of value for the amount of RAM being currently used/shared with the GPU? E.g., if I plug in a 5K external monitor, what should I expect to change?

Or is it much more complex/abstract than a single number can represent?

Comment: Hmm just checked iStat Menus, which covers this for a PCIe GPU on an older Mac but doesn't seem to have the corresponding section on an M1 iMac.

Comment: Not sure how easy this is to quantify. If I understand https://www.howtogeek.com/701804/how-unified-memory-speeds-up-apples-m1-arm-macs/ (and similar descriptions) correctly, there is no memory/RAM directly allocated to the GPU.